# System.OutOfMemoryException on server side for client files

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, client-server, networkstream

I am getting data from client and saving it to the local drive on local host .I have checked it for a file of 221MB but a test for file of 1Gb gives the following exception:

> *An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll*

Following is the code at server side where exception stems out.

**UPDATED**

Server:

```
      public void Thread()
        {
           TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(ipaddr, port);
           tcpListener.Start();
           MessageBox.Show("Listening on port" + port);      
           TcpClient client=new TcpClient();
           int bufferSize = 1024;
           NetworkStream netStream;
           int bytesRead = 0;
           int allBytesRead = 0;

           // Start listening
           tcpListener.Start();

           // Accept client
           client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
           netStream = client.GetStream();

          // Read length of incoming data to reserver buffer for it
           byte[] length = new byte[4];
           bytesRead = netStream.Read(length, 0, 4);
           int dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(length,0);

         // Read the data
           int bytesLeft = dataLength;
           byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];

           while (bytesLeft > 0)
             {

                int nextPacketSize = (bytesLeft > bufferSize) ? bufferSize : bytesLeft;

                bytesRead = netStream.Read(data, allBytesRead, nextPacketSize);
                allBytesRead += bytesRead;
                bytesLeft -= bytesRead;

             }

           // Save  to desktop
           File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\LALA\Miscellaneous\" + shortFileName, data);

          // Clean up
          netStream.Close();
          client.Close();

    }
```

I am getting the file size  first from client side followed by data.

1).Should i increase the buffer size or any other technique ?

2). `File.WriteAllBytes()` and `File.ReadAllBytes()` seems blocking and freezes the PC.Is there any async method for it to help provide the progress of file recieved at server side.

Comment: You are allocating a 1 GB byte array. No wonder you are running out of memory on a mediocre machine. Write the data into the file chunk-by-chunk using a stream.

Comment: Don't keep the entire file in memory, just write the bytes to disk (using a filestream) as soon as you receive them. You could also calculate progress at that point.

Comment: how can i calculate progress that time? @DavidLibido

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to read the whole thing to memory before writing it to disc. Just copy straight from the network stream to a `FileStream`:

```
byte[] length = new byte[4];
// TODO: Validate that bytesRead is 4 after this... it's unlikely but *possible*
// that you might not read the whole length in one go.
bytesRead = netStream.Read(length, 0, 4);
int bytesLeft = BitConverter.ToInt32(length,0);

using (var output = File.Create(@"D:\Javed\Miscellaneous\" + shortFileName))
{
    netStream.CopyTo(output, bytesLeft);
}
```

Note that instead of calling `netStream.Close()` explicitly, you should use a `using` statement:

```
using (Stream netStream = ...)
{
    // Read from it
}
```

That way the stream will be closed even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks for prompt  answer...CopyToAsync in .NET4.5 serves the same purpose..which one should i prefer for performance optimality?

Comment: @Khan: Ooh, I hadn't noticed that `CopyTo`/`CopyToAsync` have overloads which take the number of bytes to copy - I've changed my answer appropriately. As for whether you want `CopyTo` or `CopyToAsync`... the async version won't keep a thread hanging around while it's copying, but you should really decide whether you're making your whole code (or at least the handling of a whole request) async or not. It's not generally nice to only make *one* part of your code async. We don't have enough context to give advice on that front.

Comment: If i were able to make a part(where read/write takes place) of code async how wouldn't it be nice Sir

Comment: @Khan: Well again, we don't know what the rest of your code is doing. If you're going to block another thread waiting for the copying to complete, why bother making that copying itself async? It's also very easy to end up with deadlocks at the places where you switch between async and synchronous code.

Comment: All of my process is copying from client to server but i was in the search of a method/technique to show progress side-by-side or at the end of file copying!

Comment: @Skeet the Question is updated with full server code and your suggestion now?

Comment: @Khan: That's clearly *not* the full server code. `shortFileName` is never declared or initialized, for example. But if the server is *just* meant to be copying data to disk, then yes, you might want to make it asynchronous. At this point we're a long way from the original question though. If you need more help with asynchrony (after trying it for yourself) please ask a new question.

Comment: We re'nt going away sir.We are infact dealing part 2. of Question now.anyhow i try it

Comment: @Khan: A question shouldn't have a "part 2" - it should ask about *one thing*. So ask about the freeze in a separate question, and give more information - it's not at all clear what the context is here. (Again, we don't know what kind of application you've got... we know it's a server, but is this a server running as a WinForms app, or is it under IIS or something similar? What exactly do you mean by "freezes the PC"?

Answer (score 1):

The CLR has a per-object limit a bit short of 2GB. However that's the theory, in practice how much memory you can allocate depends on how much memory the framework allows you to allocate. I wouldn't expect it to allow you to allocate 1 GB data table. You should allocate smaller table, and write the data in chunks into disk file.

Comment: These days, the 64-bit CLR has support for larger arrays if you turn it on - and being able to allocate 1GB isn't *entirely* absurd... but it's clearly better to stream it.

Answer (score 1):

The "out of memory" exception happens because you are trying to place the entire file into memory before dumping it on disk. This is suboptimal, because you don't need the entire file in memory in order to write into the file: you can read it block-by-block in reasonably-sized increments, and write it out as you go.

Starting with .NET 4.0 you can use `Stream.CopyTo` method to accomplish this in a few lines of code:

```
// Read and ignore the initial four bytes of length from the stream
byte[] ignore = new byte[4];
int bytesRead = 0;
do {
    // This should complete in a single call, but the API requires you
    // to do it in a loop.
    bytesRead += netStream.Read(ignore, bytesRead, 4-bytesRead);
} while (bytesRead != 4);
// Copy the rest of the stream to a file
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Javed\Miscellaneous\" + shortFileName, FileMode.Create)) {
    netStream.CopyTo(fs);
}
netStream.Close();
```

Starting with .NET 4.5 you can use [`CopyToAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copytoasync.aspx), too, which would give you a way to do reading and writing asynchronously.

Note the code that drops the initial four bytes from the stream. This is done to avoid writing the length of the stream along with the "payload" bytes. If you have control over the network protocol, you could change the sending side to stop prefixing the stream with its length, and remove the code that reads and ignores it on the receiving side.

Comment: That's going to copy the *whole* stream... the OP knows the number of bytes to copy, and if there may be more data to handle differently after that, the overload taking the number of bytes to write should be used instead.

Comment: Maybe. It depends... we don't know enough about what protocol is involved, or whether the OP is in control of it. But I would suggest at least saying in your answer that you're assuming a change in protocol - otherwise the OP is at least going to get an unexpected 4 byte prefix...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight   What is assurity of `netStream.CopyTo(fs)` that will read all sending bytes if i change sending prefix

Comment: Modifying your code to ` using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Javed\" + FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                netStream.CopyTo(fs);
            }
            netStream.Close();
        }`

Comment: it on 'run' says An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Javed\'.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I on using a constructor with permissions faces exception and without permissions isn't rite

Comment: Yes,`using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Javed\" + FileName,FileMode.Create ,FileAccess.Write))` but still same exception

Comment: It's throwing except for anpther drive too

Comment: I don't know why .Explorer traces the path using the same string

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I would be able to use your answer  if the  `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException` is resolved

Comment: Maybe it's something wrong with the permissions on system drives

Comment: Changing all permissions on a drive!

Comment: It still hasn't been resolved despite several freaky attempts